How can i generate a table from a bibtex/ris file with a formatted citation and some extra data
I am currently working on a bibliographical review for my thesis.
During this process i have been using mendeley to import citations and manage them.
Now i have to create a table with each one of the citations i have reviewed (>300) and include the reasons why i have decided to include/exclude them in my review.
Currently i have an excel file created from an xml export of mendeley in which i have the title of the publication and the reasoning behind its inclusion/exclusion.
I need some way to mass export the citations as APA style and merge it with my excel file. I tried checking some pyhon modules without any luck.
Can anyone help me find a solution so i don't have to do it manually?
